# dbm error only when submitting python job in Slurm

Tags: python-3.6, slurm

I am running a python code on a remote machine. When I run it on the head node of the computer, it executes with no problem.

But when I use Slurm workload manager:

```
sbatch --wrap="python mycode.py" -N 1 --cpus-per-task=8 -o mycode.o
```

Then the code fails with the following error (only showing the end of the error):

```
.
.
line 91, in open
    "available".format(result))
    dbm.error: db type is dbm.gnu, but the module is not available
```

I'm just confused how a code could run fine without submitting through Slurm, but fail when I do use Slurm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compute (remote) nodes probably don't have the same software installed as the head node, or you may need to do some configuration steps before running. Check with the administrator of the cluster.